synchronizing zoom between 2 plots that have same number of X axis datapoints (Plotly.js & nextJs)
synchronizing zoom between 2 plots that have same number of X axis datapoints (Plotly.js & nextJs)
Here is what I want to achieve
currently i able to drag zoom to a region on 1 timeseries graph but i want the other timeseries graph to also zoom to that region also when user zooms in one graph by drag selecting a region the other should update and vice versa.
export const TimeSeriesChart: React.FC<TimeSeriesChartProps> = ({
  vergence,
  time,
  gaze,
  target,
  type,
  selectedRegion,
  onRegionSelected,
  onRegionDeselected,
  isSelector,
}) => {
  const handleSelected = (event: any) => {
    // Only handle selection if this chart is the selector
    // if (!isSelector || !event.range) return;
    if (!event.range) return
    const start = event.range.x[0]
    const end = event.range.x[1]
    onRegionSelected(type, start, end)
  }
  const [Plotly, setPlotly] = useState<typeof PlotlyType | null>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      // Import plotly.js only on the client side
      import('plotly.js').then(module => {
        setPlotly(module.default)
      })
    }
  }, [])
  const [plotInstance, setPlotInstance] = useState<HTMLElement | null>(null)

  const handleInitialized = (figure: any, graphDiv: Readonly<HTMLElement>) => {
    setPlotInstance(graphDiv)
  }

  const handleDeselected = () => {
    // Only handle deselection if this chart is the selector
    if (!isSelector) return
    onRegionDeselected()
    if (plotInstance !== null && Plotly && typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      const xPadding = 0.065 // Adjust the padding value as needed
      const xMin = Math.min(...time)
      const xMax = Math.max(...time)
      const xRange = xMax - xMin
      const paddedXMin = xMin - xRange * xPadding
      const paddedXMax = xMax + xRange * xPadding

      Plotly.relayout(plotInstance, {
        xaxis: {
          title: 'Time(s)',
          color: chartColors.text1,
          range: [paddedXMin, paddedXMax], // Use the padded range
        },
        yaxis: {
          title:
            type === 'Horizontal'
              ? 'Left < Horizontal Axis > Right'
              : 'Down < Vertical Axis > Up',
          color: chartColors.text1,
          range: [paddedYMin, paddedYMax], // Use the padded range
        },
      })
    }
  }

  const shapes =
    selectedRegion && !isSelector
      ? ([
          {
            type: 'rect',
            x0: selectedRegion.start,
            x1: selectedRegion.end,
            y0: 0,
            y1: 50,
            yref: 'paper',
            fillcolor: 'lightgrey',
            opacity: 0.5,
            line: {
              width: 0,
            },
          },
        ] as Partial<Plotly.Shape>[])
      : []

  const chartColors = useChartColors()
  const plotConfig = useMemo(() => {
    const vergence_trace = createTrace(time, vergence, 'Vergence')
    const gaze_trace = createTrace(time, gaze, `Gaze${type}`)
    const target_trace = createTrace(time, target, `Target${type}`)

    return {
      vergence_trace: vergence_trace,
      gaze_trace: gaze_trace,
      target_trace: target_trace,
      plotData: [vergence_trace, gaze_trace, target_trace] as Plotly.Data[],
    }
  }, [target, gaze, time, vergence])

  const yPadding = 0.3 // Adjust the padding value as needed
  const yMin = Math.min(...gaze)
  const yMax = Math.max(...gaze)
  const yRange = yMax - yMin
  const paddedYMin = yMin - yRange * yPadding
  const paddedYMax = yMax + yRange * yPadding
  const plotLayout = {
    legend: useCommonChartLegend(),
    ...useCommonChartStyle(),
    title: useCommonChartTitle(`TIME SERIES (${type})`),
    xaxis: {
      title: 'Time(s)',
      color: chartColors.text1,
    },
    yaxis: {
      title:
        type === 'Horizontal'
          ? 'Left < Horizontal Axis > Right'
          : 'Down < Vertical Axis > Up',
      color: chartColors.text1,
      range: [paddedYMin, paddedYMax],
    },
    shapes: shapes,
  }

  return (
    <ChartBox
      h={'100%'}
      w={'100%'}
      flexDirection={'column'}
      id={type}
      boxShadow={undefined}
    >
      <CommonPlot
        onInitialized={handleInitialized}
        data={plotConfig.plotData}
        onSelected={handleSelected}
        layout={plotLayout}
      />
      <Button maxWidth={'200px'} onClick={handleDeselected}>
        Clear Selection
      </Button>
    </ChartBox>
  )
}

